# How to add and use one project in another project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

I have a project based on Spring which is running successfully. Now I have created another project based on Jersey which I want to integrate with spring project in Jersey.

I have gone through internet and I added spring project in the build-path of the Jersey project.

Here the problem is whenever I run my Jersey project, it has to execute the Spring project first.

How to configure spring project in Jersey?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a dependency management/build tool such as [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/).

This way each of your projects will be a module, which can be referenced from the other project as a dependency. You can still use the first project alone and the two-dependent projects alone as wall. Then the tool lets you just simply package the resulting project in a artifact such as WAR with all the dependencies.

Here is a quick maven tutorial - [Maven in 5 Minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

It is a good idea to use such a tool in any case as it has many additional advantages:

- Lets you manage also your third party dependencies without needing to manually download the libraries and add them to the classpath
- It is much easier to use such a project in cases like continuous integration.
- You can run all your tests automatically during the build process to make sure everything works
- It resolves transitive dependencies (dependencies of your dependencies)
- It builds resulting archive file for you
- You can have multiple profiles for different environments
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Make both of your projects modules of one Maven parent pom project. This way you can build them both at the same time.